# How to use/link meson build Gstreamer in ROS Package?

Tags: cmake, linker, gstreamer, ros, pkg-config

To use latest [Gstreamer](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-build), I meson built new version with following commands.

```
meson --prefix=/media/jai/Entertainment/Software/gstreamer/gst-build-installed --reconfigure build/  
ninja -C build/  
meson install -C build/
```

Now I have this directory
[image]

And it has pkg-configs also
[image]

**What changes I have to make in Cmakelist.txt & package.xml to link this Gstreamer?**

I have tried below changes. But no luck till now.

***CMakeLists.txt***

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(mypkg)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    roscpp
    sensor_msgs
    std_msgs
    )

SET(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "/media/jai/Entertainment/Software/gstreamer/gst-build-installed/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig" $ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH})
SET(ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} "/media/jai/Entertainment/Software/gstreamer/gst-build-installed/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH})
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GST1.0 REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)

catkin_package(
    CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs
    DEPENDS Boost GST1.0
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    LIBRARIES mypkg
    )

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GST1.0_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(mypkg src/main.cpp)

add_dependencies(mypkg ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

target_link_libraries(mypkg ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${GST1.0_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS mypkg
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

install(DIRECTORY launch
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

***package.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
<name>mypkg</name>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<description>Description</description>

<maintainer email="jai@todo.todo">jai</maintainer>

<license>Apache 2.0</license>

<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>pkg-config</build_depend>

<build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>sensor_msgs</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>boost</build_export_depend>

<exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>sensor_msgs</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>pkg-config</exec_depend>

<export>

</export>
</package>
```

***main.cpp***

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <sensor_msgs/CompressedImage.h>
#include "thread"
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
extern "C"{
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "gstreamer");
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);
    g_print ("**\nGstreamer version: %s\n**\n", gst_version_string ());

    ros::spin();
}
```

**After all above modification, package is still using stock gstreamer instead of new one.** 
***OUTPUT:*** *jai@jai:~$ rosrun gstreamer gstreamer*

```
************************************
Gstreamer version: GStreamer 1.8.3
************************************
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.4
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
```

I think that it might be able to access include files but not the LIBS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use **:** (colon) to split paths when setting up PKG_CONFIG_PATH and mind the quotes:

```
SET(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "/media/jai/Entertainment/Software/gstreamer/gst-build-installed/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:$ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}")
```

You can also double-check gstreamer version with:

```
pkg_get_variable(GST_VERSION gstreamer-1.0 version)
message(STATUS "Gstreamer version:${GST_VERSION}")
```

Note, that your app should be able to find at run-time gstreamer libraries that you have built. To make this possible these should be installed to known locations from **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**. Updating this as noted by @Florian, is also possible for development purposes, as well as using runtime linker config /etc/ld.so.config.

PS

I noticed *gstappsink.h* and wonder if you are missing another gst packages in your cmakelists, e.g. gstreamer-app-1.0. Check cmake macro [find_gstreamer_component](https://github.com/ProjectArtemis/gst_video_server/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)

*Edited by Jai.*

```
gedit .bashrc

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/media/jai/Entertainment/Software/gstreamer/gst-build-installed/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.

`SET(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "/media/jai/Entertainment/Software/gstreamer/gst-build-installed/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:$ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}")`
&
`SET(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "/media/jai/Entertainment/Software/gstreamer/gst-build-installed/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig" $ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH})`.
Both result same with`pkg_get_variable(GST_VERSION gstreamer-1.0 version)` - 1.17.0.1(New gstreamer).

In my IDE if I hover around `#include <gst/gst.h>` line, it displays new gstreamer header path
But gst_version_string () still gives Old gstreamer version during execution

Comment: That is at run-time. That's different than building. Try using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to your "new" GStreamer libraries. They should then get loaded instead of the system wide available ones.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch. I edited `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `CMakeLists.txt`. Still new gstreamer(1.17) is not linked. I updated my question with full `CMakeLists.txt`, `Package.xml` & `main.cpp`

Comment: Right, Florian is talking about runtime linkage, not build-time, so this is not about cmake file. Your app should be able to find right *.so (corresponding to headers that it was built against) when starts running.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch, Thanks. I `gedit .bashrc` and added `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/media/jai/Entertainment/Software/gstreamer/gst-build-installed/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Its linking with new gstreamer.